# How do I install yarn on Windows 7 as non-administrator?

Tags: windows, windows-7, yarnpkg

How to install yarn on Windows 7 as non-administrator?

[Yarn documentation](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/#windows-tab) mentions three installation methods for Windows: `.msi` installer, Chocolatey and Scoop.

- `.msi` installer requires administrator rights even if setting installation path to `%LocalAppData%\yarn`.
- Running `choco install yarn` on a [non-administrative Chocolatey installation](https://chocolatey.org/install#non-administrative-install) fails with a 1603 error code when executing `C:\WINDOWS\System32\msiexec.exe`. The `ỳarn.MsiInstall.log` contains the following error: `Product: Yarn -- Error 1925. You do not have sufficient privileges to complete this installation for all users of the machine. Log on as administrator and then retry this installation.` The `chocolateyinstall.ps1` contains a command which is called `Start-ChocolateyProcessAsAdmin` and I don't see any flag. So I don't think that will work at all.
- Scoop requires Powershell >= 3 but it's PowerShell 2 on my Windows 7 machine.

Installing via `npm install -g yarn` works but is not recommended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the releases page for Yarn on Github contain `.tar.gz` archives, e.g. https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/releases/download/v1.7.0/yarn-v1.7.0.tar.gz which does work on my Windows 7 (x64).